Using an external resource as the source of table data in python-behave
Consider the following feature test for Behave:
Feature: Student

  Scenario Outline: New
    Given User <cn> created in YAML
     Then Verify cn matches "<cn>"
     Then Verify sn matches "<sn>"
     Then Verify givenName matches "<givenName>"

     Examples:
       | cn      | sn    | givenName |
       | blewis1 | Lewis | Bob       |
       | asmith2 | Smith | Alan      |

The ultimate goal is to verify the above attributes in LDAP with the correct values contained in a YAML input file. There are a few users and attributes so a YAML file is easier to manage. I tried the following:
[features/test.feature]
Feature: Student

  Scenario Outline: New
    Given User <cn> created in YAML
     Then Verify cn matches "<cn>"
     Then Verify sn matches "<sn>"
     Then Verify givenName matches "<givenName>"

[features/test.yml]
blewis1:
  cn: blewis1
  sn: Lewis
  givenName: Bob

asmith2:
  cn: asmith2
  sn: Smith
  givenName: Alan

[features/steps/steps.py]
import yaml

from behave import given, then

@given('User {user} created in YAML')
def search_user (context, user):
  with open ('features/test.yml', 'r') as config_fh:
    user_data = yaml.safe_load (config_fh)

  if user in user_data:
    context.user_entry = {}
    for attrib in ['cn', 'givenName', 'sn']:
      context.user_entry[attrib] = user_data[user][attrib]

  print (context.user_entry)
  assert (user == context.user_entry['cn'])

@then('Verify {attrib} matches "{value}"')
def check_attribute (context, attrib, value):
  assert (context.user_entry[attrib] == value)

If I try to run features/test.feature through Behave:
$ behave features/test.feature --no-source --no-timings \
--no-summary --no-capture --no-capture-stderr
Feature: Student

The scenario outline is not run. Looks like the lack of Examples means scenario outline is ignored. Any ideas? Maybe I just need to override how templates are rendered?
